# Fastest way to calculate time differences in C#?

Tags: c#, performance, time, timespan

It seems like there are a lot of ways to calculate time spans in c#. I am wondering which one is fastest and by that I simply means requires the least amount of processing. Let me throw out an example to illustrate exactly what I am trying to do.

```
private const int timeBetweenEvents = 250;    //delay ms
DateTime nextUpdate = DateTime.Now.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, timeBetweenEvents));
...
while(true)
{
   if (DateTime.Now > nextUpdate)
   {
       // do something
       nextUpdate = DateTime.Now.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, timeBetweenEvents));
   }
   // ...
   // do some other stuff
   // ...
}
```

another option...

```
private const int timeBetweenEvents = 250;    //delay ms
TimeSpan nextUpdate = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Add(new TimeSpan(0,0,0,timeBetweenEvents));
...
while(true)
{
   if (DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay > nextUpdate)
   {
       // do something
       nextUpdate = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, timeBetweenEvents));
   }
   // ...
   // do some other stuff
   // ...
}
```

I have also seen similar things by doing subtractions using System.Environment.TickCount. So what is the bst way to do this?

Comment: What do you want to do with this timestamps? Looks like you need just Timer

Comment: Best for what? Readability? Accuracy? Performance? Something else?

Comment: @Oded, since the title says Fastest, I would assume performance.

Comment: Your second code snippet won't even compile... you should concentrate on correctness before performance. How certain are you that the simplest code doesn't perform well enough for you? (I would also encourage you to use `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds` etc for clarity.)

Comment: It seems that calculating difference between ticks and then creating a new TimeSpan is actually faster than subtracting normally (about 7x) mmm

Comment: I think it's arbitrary which method you choose if you are doing a handful of calculations. If you are doing a significant amount, only then it'll be affected by which method you choose.

Comment: If you require the least amount of processing, rewrite your code to use Timers rather than a tight loop. That's horribly processor intensive.

Answer (score 2):

`DateTime`, `Environment.TickCount` and `Thread.Sleep` have a resolution of 30ms - which may cause problems. `Stopwatch` doesn't have this problem (on platforms that support it, i.e. pretty much any machine today) - plus the code is also a little shorter (the fastest code is code that is never executed) and clearer.

```
const long millisecondsBetweenEvents = 250;
var sw = new Stopwatch();

sw.Start();
while(true)
{
   if (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds > millisecondsBetweenEvents)
   {
      // do something
      sw.Restart();
   }
}
```

Comment: Ouch. Although answering the question that the OP asked, take a step back and look at how this code is actually operating. It's evil. The right answer is to recommend using a Timer.

Comment: @spender if you want >30ms intervals. Windows will either callback immediately, or wait 30ms if an interval of <30ms is specified. In the case you don't care (probably the 99.99999 percentile) you are right. Although in saying that I do have the 250ms constant coded in, which makes my argument somewhat moot.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for performance, at the very least cache the value of `DateTime.Now` outside of the loop. I remember reading it can be a relatively expensive function to call.

Comment: What was the reason this question was given a downvote exactly?  The author is interested in performance, Kurru made a really good point, DateTime.Now is an expensive function.

Comment: The statement `new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, timeBetweenEvents)` should also be outside of the loop.

Comment: Because the DateTime.Now variable will remain constant and the if condition will never evaluate to true ?

Comment: I meant it more as general advice, however, it could still be cached partially to reduce call count in half. Obviously you'd also need some Sleeps in there to reduce CPU usage from 100%...

Comment: Yes, so sleep the interval minus the time the execution of the Do Something code, sleeping some arbitrary interval doesnt make sense.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx)

Comment: Absolutely the correct answer. OP seems to be making a tight loop that checks times then fires events if required. A timer would do this considerably more efficiently. I prefer `System.Threading.Timer`, but each to their own.

Comment: Timer has an advantage over DateTime or StopWatch: you can get rid of the while(true) loop and use an asynchronous event instead (Timer.Elapsed).  Your link has a simple example for it.

Comment: @spender I think Jordan S can try both System.Threading.Timer and System.Timers.Timer and see which one is best for her needs

Comment: @ThiagoAlves: Unless you have supporting evidence, I'd say it's dangerous to assume that Jordan is a girl's name ;)

Comment: @ThiagoAlves: spender is correct. I am most definitely a male! Seriously, how many girls are on SO?

Comment: Hahaha, in this case please accept my apologies. I wish there were more girls here in SO and in IT career as a whole

Answer (score 0):

A `StopWatch` will have better precision.