# efficient way to get current time

Tags: c#, datetime

I am using c# and from what I understand (mainly from using c++) that getting the system time `DateTime.Now` can be slow. I am trying to improve on this by using a timer/`Stopwatch`

```
class Time {
    private DateTime _starttime;
    private Stopwatch _timer;

    public Time() {
        _timer = new Stopwatch();
        _starttime = DateTime.Now; //trying to improve on multiple calls to `DateTime.Now` by only calling it once
        _timer.start;
    }

    public DateTime Now {
        get { return _starttime + _timer.Elapsed; }
    }

}
```

Now my class can have a member `private Time _time;` and call `_time.Now;` anytime it wants to know the current time.

My current time can be off by a little bit (I'm trying to measure latency and want to know if I am slow by a couple of seconds or more), but I do want to be able to look at the current time a lot without a performance hit of numerous system calls.

While I start creating some performance tests, I was wondering if anyone knew of a better/different way (or maybe someone knows if I am completely off base here).

Comment: Where did you hear that `DateTime.Now` is slow? It isn't.

Comment: I'd say you're off base worrying about this before proving that you've got anything to worry about. How often are you actually expecting this to be called? `Stopwatch` is *not* an appropriate way of getting the current system time - it's a good way of measuring elapsed time, usually for performance testing.

Comment: Ever heard of [Premature Optimization](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/80094/73326)?

Comment: _"DateTime.Now can be slow"_ it's not slow but inaccurate for several usages such as [benchmarking](http://tech.pro/tutorial/1295/c-performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-two).

Comment: @JohnSaunders It is more something that I know from dealing with cpp and boost's ptime. I know that if DateTime.Now works like boost, then it can be improved. But I wasn't sure how all of that translated to c# since I'm still learning c#

Comment: @JonSkeet I am trying to use the current time to monitor the latency of messages in a data feed. Each message has a `time sent` field and I receive 100+ messages per minute.

Comment: @MarkB42: "100+ messages per minute" is a *tiny* number unless that "+" really means "out by several orders of magnitude". Are you really worried about that? On my laptop, calling `DateTime.Now` *10 million* times takes about 4 seconds. Calling `DateTime.UtcNow` 10 million times (which would probably be a better idea anyway - use UTC everywhere if you can) takes 82 milliseconds. Still think you need to optimize?

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't think MarkB42 needs to optimize.  I think he needs *your* laptop. :)

Comment: @JonSkeet Ha! The "+" really means I don't currently have an idea of the max number in production. I know that the dev feed I am using now I am processing too slowly so I'm researching possible optimizations I truly do not think that the time is the cause for my delay, but other SO answers like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7388853/351028) cause me to take a few minutes to look at my time on top of everything else.

Comment: @MarkB42: Now would be a good time to stop guessing and use a profiler. Performance problems are often *very* surprising - you'll get to the bottom of them far quicker by measuring and testing than by guessing, IMO. I'd still suggest using `UtcNow` instead of `Now`, mind you...

Comment: @JonSkeet I will keep all of that in mind. I do plan on profiling, where the bottlenecks are, but in looking around I had the question about the time. So I just decided to ask :)

Comment: The SkeetBot strikes again :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this question here on SO for a discussion about why DateTime.Now and DateTime.UtcNow are so slow/expensive...

[Why are DateTime.Now DateTime.UtcNow so slow/expensive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075525/why-are-datetime-now-datetime-utcnow-so-slow-expensive)

If you will look at my answer in that thread (I did not have any information on why those operations are "so slow" (if, indeed, they are)), but I did share some code from NLog that is apparently trying to optimize the retrieval of the current time in the context of possibly many requests for the current time.

In essence, when determining the current time, NLog caches the result of DateTime.UtcNow.  For future requests, if the current tick count (Environment.TickCount) is the same as last time, return the cached DateTime.UtcNow value.  Otherwise, get the current DateTime.UtcNow value and save Environment.TickCount.

Whether or not DateTime.Now and DateTime.UtcNow are "slow", the NLog code does provide an interesting way to avoid the "slow" part of getting the current time, in the case that the result of DateTime.Now (or DateTime.UtcNow) will be the same as the last time it was called.  I haven't benchmarked it, so I can't tell you if this is really faster or not.  Or, if it is, how many current time operations you will have perform before you will see a benefit.

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

I was curious, so I checked a bit. `DateTime.Now` internally calls `DateTime.UtcNow`, which in turn calls internal CLR method:

```
DateTime.GetSystemTimeAsFileTime()
```

Here is [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724397%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of the method and here is [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11743614/186822) with more details.

Comment: Importantly, it calls `UtcNow` *and then does a time zone calculation* (which isn't as fast as it might be).

Comment: When testing our applications, we found DateTime.Now is actually one of the "worst" memory allocation offenders as it performs a good chunk of TZ / culture work each time it's accessed .. DateTime.UtcNow avoids this, although both are 'more than sufficiently fast' in most contexts. DateTime.UtcNow just calls GetSystemTimeAsFileTime and does a wee bit of math so it has about the same 'performance' as the direct internal call, but is accessible and yields a more friendly DateTime object..